# Scope left Join Sub doesn't work - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel I'm making a clone of Twitter. I'm making a scope to get all the likes from the DB, but I get an error from Tinker

I know some basic SQL Queries, but this one is quite complicated, so I've got no idea what to do now.

Tweet model

```
public function scopeWithLikes(Builder $query)
    {
        $query->leftJoinSub(
            'select tweet_id, sum(liked) likes, sum(!liked) dislikes from likes group by tweet_id',
            'likes',
            'likes.tweet_id',
            'tweet.id'
        );
    }
```

Tinker command

```
App\Tweet::withLikes()->first();
```

Tinker error

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App/Tweet::scopeWithLikes() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder, instance of
>   Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder given, called in
>   C:/wamp64/www/laravel/tweety/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 1164

I hope I explained it well, but if you need more information please ask me.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I don't think you should be utilizing scopes here. According to the Laravel docs, scopes are meant to add constraints to a query, not append new data. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: Check your use statement on top of the file... your ide offers 2 in autocomplete , probably change it with the one expected in your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you are using the wrong class for your scope, scope use

Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder

as a parameter while you pass

Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder

in your Twit model file, on the top ...

remove:

```
use  Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder;
```

and paste:

```
use Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this solve the problem? Because I run into exactly the same issue.

When I change Eloquent to Query, the error message is still the same.

Also the source that is given on [Git](https://github.com/laracasts/Tweety/blob/master/app/Likable.php) uses use

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

Hubert

Comment: CAN YOU POST YOUR ERROR